# Calculating Bandpower of a Signal in Python

Tags: python, matlab, frequency, bandwidth, psd

I have to calculate the bandpower of a signal for a certain vector of frequencies in python as a project. In MATLAB it can be done using `p = bandpower(pxx,f,'psd')` where `pxx` is Power spectral density vector and `f`, is a vector of frequencies corresponding to the PSD estimates in pxx. Is there any equivalent function in python that does the same?

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547669/python-numpy-equivalent-of-bandpower-from-matlab

Answer (score 0):

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547669/python-numpy-equivalent-of-bandpower-from-matlab)

```
import scipy 

def bandpower(x, fs, fmin, fmax):
    f, Pxx = scipy.signal.periodogram(x, fs=fs)
    ind_min = scipy.argmax(f > fmin) - 1
    ind_max = scipy.argmax(f > fmax) - 1
    return scipy.trapz(Pxx[ind_min: ind_max], f[ind_min: ind_max])
```